# Starling/Workling Issue on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, workling, starling-server

I'm trying to get starting and workling working on `rails 3`, and am having some issues. I have `starling-starling` installed in the gemfile, and installed workling via:

```
rails plugin install git://github.com/purzelrakete/workling.git
```

I then wrote my worker:

```
require 'rubygems'  
require 'mechanize'  
require '/home/john/kolwizard/lib/Kol.rb'  

class BotWorker < Workling::Base  
  def bot_test(options)  
    RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER.error("testestest")  
    a = Mechanize.new  
    login(a)  
  end  
end
```

And put the following call to it in my controller:

```
BotWorker.async_bot_test()
```

I started up my starling daemon with:

```
 starling -d -P tmp/starling.pid -q log/ -p 15151
```

and then my workling monitor with:

```
RAILS_ENV=production ./script/worker_client start
```

I don't get errors with either command. However, when the controller calls the worker, nothing happens. A file is created in log, called `bot_workers_bot_test` where the uids are stored, but they never seem to get passed to the BotWorker class.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I might be doing wrong? Thanks in advance for any answers!

Comment: Did you change your workling config to make workling sending request to port 15151?